# Auto align of a table in a page

Tags: html, css

I am helping a friend with his website (URL: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/test.html). I used a table for the design and I put each single inputbox in a `<td> .. </td>`. I used Javascript for save the datas and PHP for upload them on the server. My problem is that when an user open this page, the table is not well aligned according to the background.

[Screen of my desktop.](http://prntscr.com/145nar)

As you can see, the table is insede the black rectangle, but with other screen sizes the looking is not the same. For solve this problem I used the following code:

CSS:

```
body {
      background-image:url('pictures/bgframe.png');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-attachment:fixed;
      background-position:center; 
     }

input{
         text-align:center;
         }
```

In the table I used this code:

```
<table id="tab" border="0" style="width:1200px;" align="center">
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

This code is not working because with a smaller screen, the align of the table is not the same.Can you help me? If you want, [here](http://pastebin.com/MavgXtre) there is the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should try relative CSS property, like: `width:100%;` (instead of hard-coded value in px) in order to scale it properly. Also, it might be useful to explicitly set HTML5 `<body>` CSS properties: `padding:0;margin:0;`

Comment: So I have to add width:100% on body{}?

Comment: Well, it might be any number, up to your preference. 100% will ensure full screen width.